# How to resize the width of several frozen columns in Google Sheets app?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets on Android and have several columns frozen on the left, but the app seems to have a fixed width for the frozen columns. Is it possible to change this width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't with the current version (1.19.432.04.34) of Google Sheet. Maybe it will be possible to do it with future version. For a once off (or maybe permanently), [WPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng) allows to increase the width of frozen columns.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this changes the columns themselves, but not the width of the frozen area, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: @aronisstav I understand better now and have edited my answer.